# managing colors in R for plot.ly

Tags: r, plotly

I am using the `plot.ly` library for interactive charting in a `shiny` app however I am running up against some trouble with managing the colors in the chart.

Reproducible example using plotly 4.3.5 (from [github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly)):

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dt <- data.table(campaign_week = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), category = c(rep("income",3),rep("cost",3)),
                 amount = c(100,50,35,-500,-20,-15))
dt_net <- dt[, .(amount = sum(amount)), by = campaign_week][,.(campaign_week, amount = cumsum(amount))]

y <- list(title = "Income", tickformat = "$,.0f",hoverformat = "$,.2f") 

plot_ly(dt_net, x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount, type = "scatter",
        mode= "lines+markers",
        line = list(color = "#00AEFF"), name = "Net Income") %>%
  add_trace(data = dt, x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount, color = ~category, type = "bar",
            colors = c("#00ff00", "#ff0000")) %>%
  layout(yaxis = y, barmode = "relative")
```

This creates the chart that I want, however the colours aren't being applied correctly to the `trace`. I am expecting one of the bars to be red, and the other to be green while the line is a shade of blue.

**EDIT** Add a screenshot of the `plotly` chart created

[image: Current plotly output]

Comment: This works for me, dropping the `~`. What does your plot look like?

Comment: Have added an image based on the original code provided. In response to removing the `~`; I get an error messaging saying `object 'campaign_week' not found`.

Comment: @VanceLopez what plotly version are you using? OP referenced ver. 4.3.5 (development version from github) which has a number of syntax and behaviour changes from earlier versions.

Comment: @dww I missed that... I was on 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example at https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-relative-barmode a separate add_trace for each category is the way to go.

```
plot_ly(dt_net, x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount, type = "scatter",
        mode= "lines+markers",
        line = list(color = "#00AEFF"), name = "Net Income") %>%
  add_trace(data =  dt[category=="income",] , x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount,  type = "bar", name = "income",
            marker=list(color = "#00ff00")) %>%
  add_trace(data =  dt[category=="cost",] , x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount,  type = "bar", name = "cost",
            marker=list(color = "#ff0000")) %>%
  layout(yaxis = y, barmode = "relative")
```

[image]

Note, this gives a warning, because the bar chart traces inherit `mode` and `line` attributes from the scatter chart, but these attributes are not supported for bars. You can either ignore the warnings, or you can call the barchart before the scatter to avoid them... Like this:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data =  dt[category=="income",] , x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount,  type = "bar", name = "income",
            marker=list(color = "#00ff00")) %>%
  add_trace(data =  dt[category=="cost",] , x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount,  type = "bar", name = "cost",
            marker=list(color = "#ff0000"))  %>%
  add_trace(data =  dt_net, x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount, type = "scatter", mode= "lines+markers",
            line = list(color = "#00AEFF"), name = "Net Income") %>%
  layout(yaxis = y, barmode = "relative")
```

Comment: not the cleanest solution (if I end up with other categories at some point), however the best I think I am likely to get at this point.

Comment: @Dan If you end up with many categories, you can add them in a loop. e.g. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39420523/2761575)

Answer (score 0):

I reverted the calls and added the `inherit=FALSE`:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dt <- data.table(campaign_week = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), category = c(rep("income",3),rep("cost",3)),
                 amount = c(100,50,35,-500,-20,-15))
dt_net <- dt[, .(amount = sum(amount)), by = campaign_week][,.(campaign_week, amount = cumsum(amount))]

y <- list(title = "Income", tickformat = "$,.0f",hoverformat = "$,.2f") 

plot_ly(data=dt, x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount, color = ~category, type = "bar",
            colors = c("#00ff00", "#ff0000")) %>%
  add_trace( data=dt_net, x = ~campaign_week, y = dt_net$amount, type = "scatter",
            mode= "lines+markers",
            line = list(color = "#00AEFF"), name = "Net Income", inherit=FALSE) %>%
  layout(yaxis = y, barmode = "relative")
```

Still have a problem with the legend:

[image]

Comment: Looks very promising, any thoughts on why the legend colour for the `income` doesn't match what is displayed on the chart?

Comment: There is same problem with :`plot_ly(data=dt, x = ~campaign_week, y = ~amount, color = ~category, type = "bar")`

Comment: I end up with an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'category' not found`